# Proving that the sum of prime reciprocals diverges using Borel Canteloni, 2nd version

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, divergent-series, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I'm looking on feedback on the following proof. Most importantly, did I make any fundamental  errors in my reasoning? If not, how could I make the proof more professional, adding rigour and better styllistic choices? Is my proof interesting and creative at all in your opinion?

Idea of proof and interpretation of Borel Cantelloni:

Let  $E_1, E_2,...$ be a sequence of events, then the Borel Cantelloni states that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(E_n) < \infty $, then $P(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} E_n ) = 0$, meaning that (almost surely) only finitely events can happen simultaniously. Now for some subset $S = s_1, s_2, ...$ of the integers, imagine for every $s\in S $ a corresponding (independent) coinflip that has a probability of $\frac{1}{s}$ to land on Heads. If the the reciprocals of $S$ converge, i.e. : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s_n} < \infty$ then almost surely, only finitely coinflips resulted in Heads. We will show that  assuming that the sum of prime reciprocals converges, thus assuming only finitely coinflips result in Heads, will lead to a contradiction. We will construct a random integer $r$ in the following way: We start by setting $r = 1$. Then for each prime $p_n$, we flip the corresponding coin.For each Heads, we multiply $r$ by $p_n$, and flip that coin again. We keep flipping each coin until it land on Tails, and multiplying $r$ with $p_n$ every time we flipped a Head.

The Proof:

Let $P = p_1, p_2,...$ be the set of all primes and assume that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_n} < \infty $. Let $g_n$ be a sequence of independent random geometric variables with $P(g_n = k ) = \frac{1}{p_n}^k\cdot(1-\frac{1}{p_n})$. And let $r = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}p_n^{g_n}$. And let $E_n$ be the event that $g_n > 0$. Then by Borel-Cantelloni, we have that $g_n>0$ for only finitely many $n\in N$ a.s. Since each $g_n$ is also finite a.s., we have that $r<\infty$ a.s., thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(r=n) = 1$ a.s.  Furthermore, $P(r=1)$ corresponds to the chance that every $g_n = 0 $, thus  throwing no Heads at all. And $P(r=2)$ equals the probability of throwing first a Head with the coin corresponding to $2$, and then throwing Tails for every subsequent coinflip, that is $P(r=2) = \frac{1}{2} P(r=1)$. We can apply this logic for every integer, leading to the general result $P(r=n) = \frac{1}{n} P(r=1)$ and thus:
$$1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(r=n) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} P(r=1)=  (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}) P(r=1)  $$.

But this is impossible, since $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = \infty$. Thus the right-hand side of the above equation is infinite if $P(r=1)>0$ and otherwise equals $0$, but can never equal $1$. Which proves by contradiction that the sum of prime reciprocals must diverge.

Comment: It's "Cantelli" not "Cantelloni". It looks like you are giving one definition of $r$ in the statement of your theorem and a different definition in the proof. Also, using the definition  of $r$ in the statement, it is impossible for $r$ to be $3$: $r$ must have the form $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots p_n$ for some $n$. So your proof is very unclear.

Comment: @RobArthan r can be $r=2^0 *3^1*5^0*....$ r=3 is thus $g_2 = 1$ and all other g_n being 0

Comment: That's not what the definition of $r$ in the statement of your theorem says. It appears to say that we start with $1$ and multiply by each $p_n$ in turn until we flip the first tail and then (it implies that) we stop. This probably isn't what you mean, but as I said your description is far from clear.

Comment: You throw the first coin, multiplying by 2 for every Head. When you get Tails you move to the second coin etc etc. How could I formulate that better?

Comment: By making it much clearer that you are describing a process with a nested loop: "for each prime $p_n$, we repeatedly flip the corresponding coin ...". And then you need to relate that to the formula you give for $r$ in the proof.

Comment: Or just drop the coin analogy and just define r as the product of primes raised to the power g_n, like I do later? It seems that the coins confuse people. every g_n is clearly defined so r as well right?

Comment: That sounds like a good plan.